# How do you install ´less´ command in Docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, less, pager

I'm using a mariadb container:

```
image: mariadb:10.5.8
```

While in the container and in a `mysql` session I'm trying to set:

```
pager less -SFX
```

When I run:

```
select * from sometable;
```

I get

```
sh: 1: less: not found
```

The reason I want to set `pager less -SFX` is so that the terminal output table would format correctly. How do I install `less` in this container?

Comment: Install Less onto which OS?

Comment: Why do you need to get a debugging shell inside the database itself?  Can you run the `mysql` client from another environment (maybe the host) with richer tools available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need `less` in the interactive session you can simply install it with `apt` before entering `mysql`:

```bash
apt update && apt install less
```

If you want `less` to be always installed and available you need to create a new docker image based on the `mariadb` image where you add `less`:

```dockerfile
# images/Dockerfile
FROM mariadb:10.5.8

RUN apt update && apt install -y less
```

And to use it replace the `image` property in your `docker-compose.yml` with

```yaml
    build: ./images/
```